# Android M 6.0 - SecurityException Trying to remove accounts

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-account, android-securityexception

I have an app that uses Android AccountManager (package name: com.mycompany.accounts), that adds accounts to the device and provides a login screen. I have another app (com.mycomp.actualapp), that uses the first app to add/remove accounts.

I can successfully add and remove accounts on Pre Marshmallow devices, using the following permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
```

When compiling with sdk 22 and targetting sdk 22, these permissions should be automatically granted. The following code:

```
      accountManager.removeAccount(getAccount(), activity, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> accountManagerFuture) {
            try {
                Bundle bundle = accountManagerFuture.getResult();
                boolean success = bundle.getBoolean(AccountManager.KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT);
                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.string.successfully_loggedout), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    afterLogoutSuccess(activity);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), activity.getString(R.string.failed_to_logout), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                onLogoutListener.onLogoutFinished(success);
                return;
            } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Operation cancelled exception:", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException:", e);
            } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "AuthenticatorException:", e);
            }
            onLogoutListener.onLogoutFinished(false);

        }
    }, null);
```

Fails with the following exception:

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10057 cannot remove accounts of type: com.mycompany.accounts
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
        at android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub$Proxy.removeAccount(IAccountManager.java:897)
        at android.accounts.AccountManager$7.doWork(AccountManager.java:900)
        at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask.start(AccountManager.java:1888)
        at android.accounts.AccountManager.removeAccount(AccountManager.java:897)
        at com.mycomp.actualapp.utils.LoginHelper$4.doInBackground(LoginHelper.java:282)
        at com.mycomp.actualapputils.LoginHelper$4.doInBackground(LoginHelper.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The strange thing, is that this code runs fine on Pre Marshmallow devices without any issues.

On a side note, I noticed that compiling with sdk 22 and targeting 22: Going to "Settings > Apps > My app(com.mycomp.actualapp) > Permissions" I see only two permissions, "Phone" "Storage".

I noticed that compiling with sdk 23 and targeting 23: I see three permissions, "Phone", "Storage" and "Contacts".

I have tried the following:

- Switching to compile with sdk 23 - grant all permissions in app settings, try remove account again. Still fails with the same exception.
- Compile with 22 and add the following permissions to the manifest. Make sure all permissions are granted. Still fails with the same exception:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

I am able to get the users account username and token without additional permission granting, but the removing of accounts doesn't work.
I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: were you able to solve it in the meantime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late to answer but I thought I would share my findings in case anyone else is in the same situation.

I upgraded my build to build with 23 instead of 22 as I couldn't solve it on 22. Then I **explicitly asking for the permission at runtime** to GET_ACCOUNTS before trying to do anything with them. 
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS

Further information for compiling with 23: You **don't need to ask permission** if the app shares the signature of the authenticator that manages an account. In this case, my signatures didn't match so I did need to request it. If you create an account within your app to be used within your app, you **do not need to request permission at runtime**.

Comment: How to request the signature if it doesn't match with what is in your app?

Comment: Because i am a bit confuse regarding what signature in the documentation in AccountManager are talking about?

"This method requires the caller to have a signature match with the authenticator that owns the specified account."

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly was stuck in the same thing yesterday.
In my case, I defined wrong package name in  node.
Just fix it and it will work perfectly.

`<account-authenticator>
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:accountType="Your correct packet name here" + ".accounts"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="xxx"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    >
</account-authenticator>`

If your package name is: 
`com.example.android` then the account type should be: `com.example.android.accounts`

Answer (score 0):

Checking in the source code, you can removeAccounts in two cases:

1. the account is created by your app
2. your app is a system app

Source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/05c9ecc/services/core/java/com/android/server/accounts/AccountManagerService.java#1336